# Spinner not showing selected Item or default

Tags: android, spinner

Hello I have a spinner being populated by JSON/PHP query to Mysql. This works but the Spinner shows blank upon loading app and when I click on the spinner I can see the values but If I choose a Value it does not show the selected value.

```
items.add("Choose Island");
//Get data from Database using JSON and Populate spinner
    new DownloadJSONAsync().execute();
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    Island.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

Island.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            CIsland=Island.getSelectedItemPosition();   
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Class:

```
public class DownloadJSONAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog; 
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(getJSONUrl(URL_ISLANDS));
            JSONArray data = jObj.getJSONArray("Islands");
            for(int i=0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                Country = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                Country.put(c.getInt("CountryID"), c.getString("Country"));
                String ListItem = c.getString("Country");
                items.add(ListItem);
            }
            return true;
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result==false){
        pDialog.setMessage("Could not get data");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    else{
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    }   
}
```

Layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0404B4"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.cadushideals.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="Company Add"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblTitle">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Company Name"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Description"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Address"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Tel"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Fax"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Latitude"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Longitude" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Company Valid" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Tire Customer" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:minWidth="50dip"
    android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried reading this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504970/spinner-selection-not-working-android

Answer (score 3):

In "**onPostExecute**" of your **DownloadJSONAsync**, you would want to call "**notifyDataSetChanged**" on your spinnerAdapter. In addition, you could also call "**setSelection**" on your Spinner class to have desired item to be picked. Hope this helps.

Note: Another way would be have your DownloadJSONAsync return a list of strings. and in your postexecute, do **spinnerAdapter.clear().addAll(Items);**  (This is a cleaner approach and you wont have to call notifyDataSetChanged)

Comment: Hi bond thanks for answering tried your suggestion but still same problem. I added a link to a screenshot of what I'm experiencing maybe that will give a better understanding.

Comment: Did u try updating via adapter ( see notes section) instead of updating items only?

Comment: Tried this but still same:

`new DownloadJSONAsync().execute();
  ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
  spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  spinnerAdapter.clear();
  spinnerAdapter.addAll(items);
  Island.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);`

Comment: Can you share the layout xml? also, if you put breakpoint at    CIsland=Island.getSelectedItemPosition();    are you getting the right value? Only other solution I could think of is to extend ArrayAdapter and implement getView and getDropDownView. (getView is responsible to show the selected item where as getDropDownView is responsible to show the list of items to pick from)

Comment: Added the layout. The debugging does not seem recognize the breakpoint not sure what is going on I'm debugging on the phone directly. Trying to figure out what is the issue. I did notice the logcat:
`01-06 16:55:28.921: D/AbsListView(11973): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-06 16:55:31.234: D/AbsListView(11973): onDetachedFromWindow
01-06 16:55:31.344: E/ViewRootImpl(11973): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`

when trying to select an option on the spinner.

Comment: So I added: `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Integer.toString(CIsland), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` to the onItemSelected and it seems that it does not even trigger. The error seems to be causing this issue.

Comment: I would advice that you create an Adapter that extends ArrayAdapter as indicated on previous comment. If you put break points at "getDropDownView" and "getView", you should see it getting called. You can create a layout and inflate them in those methods. Another note, in your spinner you want to define a certain width like match_parent to span across or 250dp etc because if you do wrap content, it will resize based on the String you have there.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I solved the problem not sure why it works now vs before but all I did was move "items.add("Choose Island");" outside the class DownloadJSONAsync, put the line before calling the class and it started working properly.

I edit the code with the working code incase anyone wants to do something similar.